# App locker is not getting the current App package name in sdk >= 20 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, applocker

I am working on application locker in this regard I build code which can see here below. My question is my code is running below version 20 (Lollipop) and not working with above version 20.

I have been applied almost all solutions printed at this site but failed. Some times but very rarely I got that app locker working but for limited apps like settings.  Here is how I am getting package name:

```
 private String getTopPackageName() {


    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time-1000*1000, time);
        if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }
        }
    } else {
        mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
    }

    return currentApp;
}
```

Also here is my whole Service Class

```
public class AppLockService extends Service {

public static final String BROADCAST_SERVICE_STARTED = "com.appslocker.locker.intent.action.service_started";
/**
 * Sent to {@link MainActivity} when the service has been stopped
 */
public static final String BROADCAST_SERVICE_STOPPED = "com.appslocker.locker.intent.action.service_stopped";
/**
 * This category allows the receiver to receive actions relating to the
 * state of the service, such as when it is started or stopped
 */
public static final String CATEGORY_STATE_EVENTS = "com.appslocker.locker.intent.category.service_start_stop_event";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x1234AF;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0xABCD32;
private static final String TAG = "AppLockService";

/**
 * Use this action to stop the intent
 */
private static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.apsscloker.locker.intent.action.stop_lock_service";
/**
 * Starts the alarm
 */
private static final String ACTION_START = "com.appslocker.locker.intent.action.start_lock_service";
/**
 * When specifying this action, the service will initialize everything
 * again.<br>
 * This has only effect if the service was explicitly started using
 * {@link #getRunIntent(Context)}
 */
private static final String ACTION_RESTART = "com.appslocker.locker.intent.action.restart_lock_service";

private static final String EXTRA_FORCE_RESTART = "com.appslocker.locker.intent.extra.force_restart";
private ActivityManager mActivityManager;

/**
 * 0 for disabled
 */
private long mShortExitMillis;

private boolean mRelockScreenOff;
private boolean mShowNotification;

private boolean mExplicitStarted;
private boolean mAllowDestroy;
private boolean mAllowRestart;
private Handler mHandler;
private BroadcastReceiver mScreenReceiver;
private String currentApp;
/**
 * This map contains locked apps in the form<br>
 * <PackageName, ShortExitEndTime>
 */
private Map<String, Boolean> mLockedPackages;
private Map<String, Runnable> mUnlockMap;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
    return new LocalBinder();
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public AppLockService getInstance() {
        return AppLockService.this;
    }
}

private final class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Screen ON");
            // Trigger package again
            mLastPackageName = "";
            startAlarm(AppLockService.this);
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Screen OFF");
            stopAlarm(AppLockService.this);
            if (mRelockScreenOff) {
                lockAll();
            }
        }
    }
}

;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

/**
 * Starts everything, including notification and repeating alarm
 *
 * @return True if all OK, false if the service is not allowed to start (the
 * caller should stop the service)
 */
private boolean init() {
    Log.d(TAG, "init");
    if (new PrefUtils(this).isCurrentPasswordEmpty()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Not starting service, current password empty");
        return false;
    }


    mHandler = new Handler();
    mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    mUnlockMap = new HashMap<>();
    mLockedPackages = new HashMap<>();
    mScreenReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(mScreenReceiver, filter);

    final Set<String> apps = PrefUtils.getLockedApps(this);
    for (String s : apps) {
        mLockedPackages.put(s, true);
    }
    PrefUtils prefs = new PrefUtils(this);
    boolean delay = prefs.getBoolean(R.string.pref_key_delay_status,
            R.bool.pref_def_delay_status);

    if (delay) {
        int secs = prefs.parseInt(R.string.pref_key_delay_time,
                R.string.pref_def_delay_time);
        mShortExitMillis = secs * 1000;
    }

    mRelockScreenOff = prefs.getBoolean(
            R.string.pref_key_relock_after_screenoff,
            R.bool.pref_def_relock_after_screenoff);

    startNotification();
    startAlarm(this);

    // Tell MainActivity we're done
    Intent i = new Intent(BROADCAST_SERVICE_STARTED);
    i.addCategory(CATEGORY_STATE_EVENTS);
    sendBroadcast(i);
    return true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "test");
    if (intent == null || ACTION_START.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (!mExplicitStarted) {
            Log.d(TAG, "explicitStarted = false");
            if (init() == false) {
                doStopSelf();
                return START_NOT_STICKY;
            }
            mExplicitStarted = true;
        }
        checkPackageChanged();
    } else if (ACTION_RESTART.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if (mExplicitStarted
                || intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_FORCE_RESTART, false)) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "ACTION_RESTART (force="
                            + intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_FORCE_RESTART,
                            false));
            // init();
            doRestartSelf(); // not allowed, so service will restart
        } else {
            doStopSelf();
        }
    } else if (ACTION_STOP.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_STOP");
        doStopSelf();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private String mLastPackageName;


private void checkPackageChanged() {
    final String packageName = getTopPackageName();
    // final String completeName = packageName + "/"
    // + top.topActivity.getShortClassName();

    if (!packageName.equals(mLastPackageName)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "appchanged " + " (" + mLastPackageName + ">"
                + packageName + ")");

        onAppClose(mLastPackageName, packageName);
        onAppOpen(packageName, mLastPackageName);
    }

    // prepare for next call
    mLastPackageName = packageName;
    // mLastCompleteName = completeName;
}

private void onAppOpen(final String open, final String close) {
    if (mLockedPackages.containsKey(open)) {
        onLockedAppOpen(open);
    }
}

private void onLockedAppOpen(final String open) {
    final boolean locked = mLockedPackages.get(open);
    // Log.d(TAG, "onLockedAppOpen (locked=" + locked + ")");
    if (locked) {
        showLocker(open);
    }
    removeRelockTimer(open);
}

private void showLocker(String packageName) {
    Intent intent = LockService.getLockIntent(getApplicationContext(), packageName);
    intent.setAction(LockService.ACTION_COMPARE);
    intent.putExtra(LockService.EXTRA_PACKAGENAME, packageName);
    startService(intent);

}

private void showLockerForCategory(String category) {
    Intent intent = LockService.getLockIntentForCategory(this, category);
    intent.setAction(LockService.ACTION_COMPARE);
    intent.putExtra(LockService.EXTRA_CATEGORY, category);
    startService(intent);

}

private void onAppClose(String close, String open) {
    if (mLockedPackages.containsKey(close)) {
        onLockedAppClose(close, open);
    }
}

private void onLockedAppClose(String close, String open) {
    //showInterstitial();

    setRelockTimer(close);

    if (getPackageName().equals(close) || getPackageName().equals(open)) {
        // Don't interact with own app
        return;
    }

    if (mLockedPackages.containsKey(open)) {
        // The newly opened app needs a lock screen, so don't hide previous
        return;
    }
    LockService.hide(this);
}

private void setRelockTimer(String packageName) {
    boolean locked = mLockedPackages.get(packageName);
    if (!locked) {
        if (mShortExitMillis != 0) {
            Runnable r = new RelockRunnable(packageName);
            mHandler.postDelayed(r, mShortExitMillis);
            mUnlockMap.put(packageName, r);
        } else {
            lockApp(packageName);
        }
    }
}

private void removeRelockTimer(String packageName) {
    // boolean locked = mLockedPackages.get(packageName);
    // if (!locked) {
    if (mUnlockMap.containsKey(packageName)) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUnlockMap.get(packageName));
        mUnlockMap.remove(packageName);
    }
}

/**
 * This class will re-lock an app
 */
private class RelockRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String mPackageName;

    public RelockRunnable(String packageName) {
        mPackageName = packageName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lockApp(mPackageName);
    }
}

List<RunningTaskInfo> mTestList = new ArrayList<>();


private String getTopPackageName() {


    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time-1000*1000, time);
        if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }
        }
    } else {
        mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
    }

    return currentApp;

   /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
        return mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
       // mClassName = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).getClass().getName();
    } else {
         return  mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
       // mClassName = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
    }*/

}

public void unlockApp(String packageName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "unlocking app (packageName=" + packageName + ")");
    if (mLockedPackages.containsKey(packageName)) {
        mLockedPackages.put(packageName, false);
    }
}

private void lockAll() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : mLockedPackages.entrySet()) {
        entry.setValue(true);
    }
}

void lockApp(String packageName) {
    if (mLockedPackages.containsKey(packageName)) {
        mLockedPackages.put(packageName, true);
    }
}

private void startNotification() {

    // Start foreground anyway
    startForegroundWithNotification();

    mShowNotification = new PrefUtils(this).getBoolean(
            R.string.pref_key_show_notification,
            R.bool.pref_def_show_notification);

}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void startForegroundWithNotification() {
    Log.d(TAG, "showNotification");

    boolean hide = new PrefUtils(this).getBoolean(
            R.string.pref_key_hide_notification_icon,
            R.bool.pref_def_hide_notification_icon);
    int priority = hide ? Notification.PRIORITY_MIN
            : Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    String title = getString(R.string.notification_title);
    String content = getString(R.string.notification_state_locked);
    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    nb.setContentTitle(title);
    nb.setContentText(content);
    nb.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    nb.setContentIntent(pi);
    nb.setOngoing(true);
    nb.setPriority(priority);

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, nb.build());
}

public static void start(Context c) {
    startAlarm(c);
}

/**
 * @param c
 * @return The new state for the service, true for running, false for not
 * running
 */
public static boolean toggle(Context c) {
    if (isRunning(c)) {
        stop(c);
        return false;
    } else {
        start(c);
        return true;
    }

}

public static boolean isRunning(Context c) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (AppLockService.class.getName().equals(
                service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Starts the service
 */
private static void startAlarm(Context c) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = getRunIntent(c);
    SharedPreferences sp = PrefUtils.prefs(c);
    String defaultPerformance = c.getString(R.string.pref_val_perf_normal);
    String s = sp.getString(c.getString(R.string.pref_key_performance),
            defaultPerformance);
    if (s.length() == 0)
        s = "0";
    long interval = Long.parseLong(s);
    Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling alarm (interval=" + interval + ")");
    long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, startTime, interval, pi);
}

private static PendingIntent running_intent;

private static PendingIntent getRunIntent(Context c) {
    if (running_intent == null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(c, AppLockService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_START);
        running_intent = PendingIntent.getService(c, REQUEST_CODE, i, 0);
    }
    return running_intent;
}

private static void stopAlarm(Context c) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(getRunIntent(c));
}

/**
 * Stop this service, also stopping the alarm
 */
public static void stop(Context c) {
    stopAlarm(c);
    Intent i = new Intent(c, AppLockService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_STOP);
    c.startService(i);
}

/**
 * Re-initialize everything.<br>
 * This has only effect if the service was explicitly started using
 * {@link #start(Context)}
 */
public static void restart(Context c) {
    Intent i = new Intent(c, AppLockService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_RESTART);
    c.startService(i);
}

/**
 * Forces the service to stop and then start again. This means that if the
 * service was already stopped, it will just start
 */
public static void forceRestart(Context c) {
    Intent i = new Intent(c, AppLockService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_RESTART);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_FORCE_RESTART, true);
    c.startService(i);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: (mAllowRestart=" + mAllowRestart + ")");
    if (mScreenReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(mScreenReceiver);
    if (mShowNotification)
        stopForeground(true);

    if (mAllowRestart) {
        start(this);
        mAllowRestart = false;
        return;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy (mAllowDestroy=" + mAllowDestroy + ")");
    if (!mAllowDestroy) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Destroy not allowed, restarting service");
        start(this);
    } else {
        // Tell MainActivity we're stopping
        Intent i = new Intent(BROADCAST_SERVICE_STOPPED);
        i.addCategory(CATEGORY_STATE_EVENTS);
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
    mAllowDestroy = false;
}

private void doStopSelf() {
    stopAlarm(this);
    mAllowDestroy = true;
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
}

private void doRestartSelf() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting allowrestart to true");
    mAllowRestart = true;
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

And Here is my Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />

<!-- permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/application_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:node="replace">
    <activity
        android:name="com.appslocker.locker.ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/application_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.appslocker.locker.lock.AppLockService" />
    <service android:name="com.appslocker.locker.lock.LockService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.appslocker.locker.receivers.BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".DeviceAdmenReciever"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service
        android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
    </service>


</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

your application is not working because in lollipop when you install the application in your device,by default all the permission will be given by android,But From the Marshmallow the Google has added functionality that when you install any application and if it has any permission then it will ask the user for the permission,so you should search for the "runtime permission in android" in Google,And you will get the perfect code for your application.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Well Rest of all application which i installed only ask for "App Usage Permission" I also have been given this permission in my application...

Comment: My application get locked but after two minute... not at the same time it locked after 2 minutes ultimate... WWhy is it so?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i really don't have any idea about this sorry.

Comment: can i send you my complete code that you can realize it more accurately ...

Comment: No problem at all. I will try my best .

Comment: aliasgar.one1@gmail.com, you can email me your code here